# Obtain progress by two values

Tags: php, upload, percentage, filesize

For example i have two values:

`$total_size   = 158720655; //first value (static size)`

`$current_size = 149720600; //second value (increasing size)`

Now, I want to get value by 100 percentage (%).

**EDIT**:

With the help of @Léa Gris, this problem was fixed , here is full php code:

`$total_size   = 158720655;`

`$current_size = 149720600;`

`$progress = ( 100 * $current_size ) / $total_size;`

`echo floor($progress) . '%';` // eg: 98% .

Thanks

Comment: Is that PHP I see? Tag in the language as an edit.

Comment: It is unclear what language this is written into. A percent calculation is a simple `cursor ÷ reference × 100`. This should not be a big deal in any language that can do floating-point arithmetic. If your language only know about integer, you do `( 100 × cursor ) ÷ reference`, or with your variables `$progress = ( 100 * $current_size ) / total_size`

Comment: @Léa Gris. Thank you very much. i can fix this with "( 100 * $current_size ) / $total_size".
thanks again

Comment: Can you edit out your answer from your question post, and post an answer to your own question? Also add a tag of your language, or tell what language it is. @uprego mentioned PHP, do you confirm?